# Rails joins with select issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am trying to follow the mantra of "select only what you need" when making database calls in my rails applications. Currently I am eager loading all users against their posts, however I notice that this selects every column from the user table for each users.

I have tried to use a join instead which offers a much easier way to select what specific attributes I need, however I am using paperclip and the user has_attached_file. I currently haven't found a way to include this in the join.

I was just wondering if anyone had any suggestions or tips on what the best way to load both users and posts is in terms of database performance?

Currently to retrieve users I am simply using this sort of syntax:

```
Post.all.includes(:user)
```

Comment: Can you post the current code you're using (to fetch your users). Also your User and Post models might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Post.eager_load(:user)`? Should fetch all the Post fields and all the User fields in a single query, and instantiate AR objects for each. Paperclip attachment would be stored in the user table under 4-5 fields starting with the same prefix. Those should be loaded through `Post.eager_load(:user)`.

The only reason this *wouldn't* work is if the association between Post and User is polymorphic.

Comment: Would that allow me to select specific columns for the user table? Currently the way the Rails include overrides select means that all columns are being retrieved (the include query looks like "select users.* from users where users.id in (1,2,etc)".

I'd rather grab only what I need from the users table (I don't really want to be selecting the "created_at" attribute when I just need the users name and id for example).

Comment: No, eager loading using this method does not appear to allow you to limit which columns are brought back from either table. However, you could grab limited columns from each in just two queries using something like: `posts = Post.select('subject, body, user_id'); users = User.select('name, email').where(id: posts.map(&:user_id))`

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Unless one of the tables includes a large TEXT column you plan to exclude or an absurd number of columns it is likely your approach of limiting the columns brought back is an example of **premature optimization**. Instantiating ActiveRecord objects is expensive. So expensive that reducing the amount of data brought back from SQL will likely result in little if any performance increase since your app will still be spending most of its time creating the base active record objects. Adding a little extra data to them generally isn't going to significantly impact performance.

Comment: Also, its likely that one single query bringing back all the data is faster, and obviously less complex, then doing it in two queries. The added data is likely less of a penalty than the added query.